# lambda collections question help needed dealing with iterating over multiple collections

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert an existing code to Lamda expression.

```
Map<Integer, List<Permission>> rpMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> loginAccessCodes = loginAccessDao.getAuthorizedPermissions(loginId);
List<AccessCode> roles = roleDAO.getAllRoles();

for (AccessCode accessCode : roles) {
    List<Permission> rolePermissions = rolePermissionDAO.getRolePermissions(accessCode.getAcCodeId());
    for (Permission permission: rolePermissions) {
        if (! loginAccessCodes.contains(permission.getPermId())) {
            permission.setChecked(false);
            permission.setGrayed(true);
        }
    }
    rpMap.put(accessCode.getAcCodeId(), rolePermissions);
}
```

So far I have:

```
List<Permission> permissions = roles.stream()
                                    .map(AccessCode -> rolePermissionDAO.getRolePermissions(AccessCode.getAcCodeId()))
                                    .flatMap(rolePermissions -> rolePermissions.stream())
                                    .filter(permission -> !loginAccessCodes.contains(permission.getPermId()))
                                    .map(permission -> { permission.setChecked(false); permission.setGrayed(true); return permission; })
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason why it's not good to use streams(lambda expression) in your current context is that you end up modifying and object `Permission` under certain `filter` conditions to set few of its attributes.

Another thing that is not clear is the relation between the `accessCode.getAcCodeId()` and `permission.getPermId()`. Under the assumption that these two are equivalent, you could have expressed the iterative approach as:

```
Map<Integer, List<Permission>> rpMap = roles.stream()
        .map(accessCode -> getRolePermissions(accessCode.getAcCodeId()))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(permission -> !loginAccessCodes.contains(permission.getPermId()))
        // following is what fails the purpose of using streams here
        .map(permission -> {
            permission.setChecked(false);
            permission.setGrayed(true);
            return permission;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Permission::getPermId));
```

Also, if the relationship between those two `ids` could be derived appropriately, you could further modify this approach to(do take note of the comments) :

```
Map<Integer, List<Permission>> rpMap = roles.stream()
        // filter based on accessCode logic itself
        .filter(accessCode -> !loginAccessCodes.contains(accessCode.getAcCodeId()))
        // set the parameters within function called inside 'map'
        .map(accessCode -> getRolePermissionsWithFlagsSet(accessCode.getAcCodeId()))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // flat it to Stream<Permission>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Permission::getPermId)); // group it using the 'id' (Integer)
```